# Make object expire given a state change in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

Is it possible in Rust to explicitly provide context on when an object expires? For instance, imagine a graph manipulation code that does something like this:

```
// borrow an edge from the graph
let edge : &Edge = graph.findEdge( ... );
// modify the edge
let new_edge : &Edge = graph.splitEdge(edge, vertex); 
// the old edge is invalid now, this should be an compiler error now!
edge.something
```

In general, is there some way to connect a lifetime of an object to a state or a state change?

Answer (score 1):

If you match your code to your comments, you will get an compiler error, although not at the position you want. Your current code is basically [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b1f26cccd66962c6fb0145e545275c89&version=stable&backtrace=0). In this case `split_edge` looks like this:

```
fn split_edge(&self, edge: &Edge) -> &Edge {}
```

This does not allow you to change either the graph or the edge. So this function is not able to invalidate the edge. If you borrow self as mutable, you will get a compiler error, because you already borrow self as immutable:

```
fn split_edge(&mut self, edge: &Edge) -> &Edge {}
// error: cannot borrow `graph` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable [--explain E0502]
```

You would also run into errors if you borrow edge mutable instead.

If edge is not really invalidated, by you just want to avoid reusing it, just reuse the variable name `edge` instead of `new_edge`.

```
let edge : &Edge = graph.find_edge();
let edge : &Edge = graph.split_edge(edge);
```

Comment: I do not quite understand why the error E0502 occurs in the first place. Sure, I borrow 'graph' for the invocation of the find_edge() method, but the function returns  before split_edge() is called, so shouldn't the borrowed reference expire by then? How should I go about if I really want to have the edge invalidated and not just reuse the variable?

Comment: When you call `let edge : &Edge = graph.findEdge( ... );`, `edge` is borrowed from `graph` until it (`edge`) goes out of scope. In my example that is until the end of `main()`. It is difficult for me to understand your exact requirements, so I can't say what you must change. But it seems strange to me that you pass the result of `find_edge` to `split_edge`. For example, can't you add the parameters of `find_edge` to `split_edge`? Maybe combined with a additional block to limit the lifetime of `edge`?

Comment: Semantically, splitting an edge in a graph (regardless of being directed or not) should either invalidate that edge completely, or modify the given edge while creating a new one. I suppose it's up to OP to choose which behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So if I understand this correctly, the way to work around this would be to explicitly restrict the lifetime of 'edge', e.g. by combining functionality of find and split? Unfortunately, this would take a lot of flexibility away, as the graph is being iterated and split at an unpredictable fashion. What I wanted to do is achieve algorithmic safety in the sense that no reference to the graph substate can survive graph invalidation. In particular the Edge type doesn't even need to be a pointer - it could be an integer index to an internal table of the edge...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that can be done:

1. `find_edge` can produce a `&mut` reference to the edge. Then `split_edge` will end up transferring the exclusive borrow into the reference it returns, making it inaccessible to the caller.
2. `find_edge` can instead be `take_edge`. That is, it produces a non-copyable object that represents the edge. `split_edge`, of course, will consume it.